# What's my roommate's first name?

Tags: cipher, steganography

This morning before leaving, I had a little discussion with my roommate. But what is his first name?

> Hey. You're up early today.
>   - Hey. Yeah I went running. And I took the opportunity to go buy some snacks for tonight's party.
>   - Cool I'll go get some drinks on my way back.
>   - OK see you soon.

Comment: Plot Twist: The words in the sentence are actually names with bad punctuation... For example, the roommate's name could be "Hey". And "TheOpportunity" is the other friend that the roommate took out to buy snacks for a party being thrown by a friend named "Tonight". So the OP decides to bring another friend "SomeDrinks" while returning for the party. Finally, if we stretch it a bit, OP's name is "OK".

Comment: His name is Bob and he just wanted to be anonymous :(

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Is he called:

> Eric

Using

> Morse on the -s and .s gets us . .-. .. -.-., or E R I C

Comment: Wow. You are so much faster than my poor friends who are still searching since 3 days. But I am a little disappointed that she has stayed so little time, here. I was proud of it and you ruin everything :'(

Comment: I wouldn't be disheartened, there are a lot of Puzzlers here who spend a lot of time and thought on complex puzzles, someone was bound to solve it. This one is quite short, so there is not much material to work on. There are only a few ways a word can be hidden in plaintext after all :)

Comment: This is absolutely not a complaint, I was just very proud to have found this idea and seeing my friends searching I thought it would stay at least one day here :) Next time i'll come with a more complexe, more complete, more complicated, with more components and I run out of relevant words starting with 'com'.

Comment: Why is this the roommate's name rather than the name of the person presenting the dialog or the name of the guest of honor at the party or ...?

Comment: Just because it's the first thing I thought about. The whole discussion was created after choosing the name in question and it changed several times before I posted my riddle here.

Answer (score 2):

I would try  :

> Andi from "And I"

Right ?